# How to add a django rest framework authentication in Route?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, jwt, django-rest-framework-jwt

How to add a django rest framework authentication in Route?

I am using JWT for authentication of my application.
Everything works perfectly.

What I need to know is how can I authenticate a particular Route based on REST Framework and JWT

example

```
from rest_framework.permissions import IsAuthenticated

path(r'modulo/app/aula/<modalidade>', IsAuthenticated  AppAulaAdd.as_view(),     name='app_aula')
```

or

```
from rest_framework.decorators import authentication_classes

path(r'modulo/app/aula/<modalidade>',  authentication_classes(AppAulaAdd.as_view()),     name='app_aula')
```

Both does not work.

Comment: What you mean by *"particular url"* ? i don't get that

Comment: Sorry. It would be routes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're mixing concepts in your question. Permission classes control access to resources based on the status of the user in your system or in a session (i.e. IsAuthenticated, IsStaff, etc), while authentication classes control the method to authenticate the user, for example BasicAuthentication or in your case JSONWebTokenAuthentication. Also, you should add both types of classes directly in your views, it's better practice (from [https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/)](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/):

```
class ExampleView(APIView):
    authentication_classes = (SessionAuthentication, BasicAuthentication)
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)
```

But if for some reason it's 100% necessary to add the permission in your urls file (routes), you can do the following:

```
from rest_framework.decorators import permission_classes
from rest_framework.permissions import IsAuthenticated

path(r'modulo/app/aula/<modalidade>', (permission_classes([IsAuthenticated])(AppAulaAdd)).as_view(), name='app_aula')
```

Hope it helps.